# Issue with Passing Vehicle Type Parameter to API

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I am encountering an issue with passing the type of vehicle as a parameter to an API in my React application. The problem arises when attempting to pass the variable "vehicle" to the API endpoint; it receives undefined instead of "carros", "motos", or "caminhoes".

Here is the relevant code from my project:

```js
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react'
import { Brand } from '../pages/VehicleBrand'

const api = createApi({
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: 'https://parallelum.com.br/fipe/api/v1',
  }),
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getBrand: builder.query<Brand[], string>({
      query: (vehicle) => `${vehicle}/marcas`,
    }),
  }),
})

export const { useGetBrandQuery } = api

export default api
```

```js
import { PayloadAction, createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

export type vehicleState = {
  vehicle: string
}

const initialState: vehicleState = {
  vehicle: 'carros',
}

const vehicleSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'vehicle',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    change: (state, action: PayloadAction<string>) => {
      state.vehicle = action.payload
    },
  },
})

export const { change } = vehicleSlice.actions

export default vehicleSlice.reducer
```

```
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom'
import MainBox from '../../components/MainBox'
import { useGetBrandQuery } from '../../services/api'

export type Brand = {
  codigo: string
  nome: string
}

type VehicleParams = {
  vehicle: string
}

const VehicleBrand = () => {
  const { vehicle } = useParams() as VehicleParams
  const { data: brand } = useGetBrandQuery(vehicle!)

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <MainBox
        children="Selecione a marca do veículo"
        to="/VehicleModel"
        selectIsVisible={true}
        btnChildren="Buscar"
        resultIsVisible={false}
        brand={brand}
      />
    </div>
  )
}

export default VehicleBrand
```

```js
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import vehicleSlice from './reducers/vehicle'
import api from '../services/api'

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    vehicle: vehicleSlice,
    [api.reducerPath]: api.reducer,
  },
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware().concat(api.middleware),
})

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>

export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch
```

```
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import * as S from './styles'
import { change } from '../../store/reducers/vehicle'

const Header = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  const handleChangeVehicle = (vehicle: string) => {
    dispatch(change(vehicle))
  }

  return (
    <S.HeaderDiv>
      <S.Container className="container">
        <S.Title to="/">ConsultaFipe</S.Title>
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <S.NavLink onClick={() => handleChangeVehicle('carros')}>
              Carros
            </S.NavLink>
            <S.NavLink onClick={() => handleChangeVehicle('motos')}>
              Motos
            </S.NavLink>
            <S.NavLink onClick={() => handleChangeVehicle('caminhoes')}>
              Caminhões
            </S.NavLink>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </S.Container>
    </S.HeaderDiv>
  )
}

export default Header
```

I have tried debugging the issue but haven't been able to find a solution. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

I need to read the value of "vehicle" in the fetch in the api query. The "GET" will be done like this: "GET: [https://parallelum.com.br/fipe/api/v1/carros/marcas"](https://parallelum.com.br/fipe/api/v1/carros/marcas%22) where the value is "car" will receive the value of vehicle.

```js
import { Brand } from '../pages/VehicleBrand'

const api = createApi({
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: 'https://parallelum.com.br/fipe/api/v1',
  }),
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getBrand: builder.query<Brand[], string>({
      query: (vehicle) => `${vehicle}/marcas`,
    }),
  }),
})

export const { useGetBrandQuery } = api

export default api
```

The console return this error: VM8:6
GET https://parallelum.com.br/fipe/api/v1/undefined/marcas 400 (Bad Request)

This is the routes.tsx file:

```
import { Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import Home from './pages/Home'
import VehicleModel from './pages/VehicleModel'
import VehicleYear from './pages/VehicleYear'
import VehicleBrand from './pages/VehicleBrand'
import VehicleInfo from './pages/VehicleInfo'

const PagesRouter = () => {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
      <Route path="/VehicleBrand" element={<VehicleBrand />} />
      <Route path="/VehicleModel" element={<VehicleModel />} />
      <Route path="/VehicleYear" element={<VehicleYear />} />
      <Route path="/VehicleInfo" element={<VehicleInfo />} />
    </Routes>
  )
}

export default PagesRouter
```

Comment: So where exactly are you expecting or wanting to read this "vehicle" value? On one hand you are setting some `state.vehicle.vehicle` value in your Redux store, and on the other you are reading a `vehicle` route path parameter. Which is it you want to use to make the query? Please [edit] to clarify the problem and include a ***complete*** [mcve] of the relevant code you are working with.

Comment: I edited the text, if you need any more information you can ask me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Issue

It appears you have navigation items that set a `vehicle` value in your Redux store, e.g. `state.vehicle.vehicle` while at the same time the `VehicleBrand` component is expecting to read a `vehicle` value from the route params.

The issue is that there aren't any routes that provide any route params and `VehicleBrand` doesn't read the current `vehicle` value from state.

## Solutions

### Navigating to and read `vehicle` from route parameters

Update the route definitions to include a `vehicle` path parameter.

```
const PagesRouter = () => {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
      <Route
        path="/VehicleBrand/:vehicle" // <-- add path parameter
        element={<VehicleBrand />}
      />
      <Route path="/VehicleModel" element={<VehicleModel />} />
      <Route path="/VehicleYear" element={<VehicleYear />} />
      <Route path="/VehicleInfo" element={<VehicleInfo />} />
    </Routes>
  );
};
```

Update the navigation to include a vehicle value in the target path. This is just an example of passing the target path as a prop to be used as a `Link` component target.

```
const Header = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const handleChangeVehicle = (vehicle: string) => {
    dispatch(change(vehicle));
  };

  return (
    <S.HeaderDiv>
      <S.Container className="container">
        <S.Title to="/">ConsultaFipe</S.Title>
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <S.NavLink
              to="/VehicleBrand/carros"
              onClick={() => handleChangeVehicle('carros')}
            >
              Carros
            </S.NavLink>
            <S.NavLink
              to="/VehicleBrand/motos"
              onClick={() => handleChangeVehicle('motos')}
            >
              Motos
            </S.NavLink>
            <S.NavLink
              to="/VehicleBrand/caminhoes"
              onClick={() => handleChangeVehicle('caminhoes')}
            >
              Caminhões
            </S.NavLink>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </S.Container>
    </S.HeaderDiv>
  );
};
```

Update `VehicleBrand` to skip the query if `vehicle` parameter value is falsey.

```
const VehicleBrand = () => {
  const { vehicle } = useParams() as VehicleParams;
  const { data: brand } = useGetBrandQuery(vehicle, { skip: !vehicle });

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <MainBox
        children="Selecione a marca do veículo"
        to="/VehicleModel"
        selectIsVisible={true}
        btnChildren="Buscar"
        resultIsVisible={false}
        brand={brand}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

### Read `vehicle` from state

Select the `vehicle` value from state.

```
const VehicleBrand = () => {
  const { vehicle } = useSelector((state: AppState) => state.vehicle);
  const { data: brand } = useGetBrandQuery(vehicle, { skip: !vehicle });

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <MainBox
        children="Selecione a marca do veículo"
        to="/VehicleModel"
        selectIsVisible={true}
        btnChildren="Buscar"
        resultIsVisible={false}
        brand={brand}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```